# Branch.io link data not available if app is not opened from App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking, branch.io

I have Branch.io links which direct the user to my app in the iOS app store. If the user clicks on the link, then clicks "Download", then clicks "Open" from within the App Store, the branch.io link data is present, as expected.

If the user clicks the branch.io link, then clicks "Download", then clicks on the downloaded app from the home screen (as opposed to in the app store), then the branch.io link data is NOT present.

Is this expected behavior? If not, any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: no, definitely not expected behavior! Would you mind sending in a [support ticket](https://support.branch.io) for this so that we can debug what's going on from the back end?

Comment: @AlexG Did you find solution for it, please guide i am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior described, link data being available when the app is opened from the App Store but not when opened via the app icon on the home screen, sounds like an issue with the testing environment or the test plan, not with anything that has been done wrong with the Branch integration.

Here is how Branch works: when a Branch link is tapped, an entry is created in a table of outstanding "link clicks" on the Branch back end. Each time an app that has the Branch SDK integrated becomes active, the SDK reaches out to the Branch back end to identify any outstanding link clicks where:

- The app's Branch key is identical to the link's Branch key
- The link click occurred on the same device

If there is an outstanding link click for the app on the device, Branch returns the data for the link to the app and increments install/open counts appropriately.

The salient point here is that Branch is agnostic with regards to how the app actually opens: as long as Branch can match a "link click" event with an "app open" event, the app will receive link data. Branch is not relying on any back-end integration with the App Store to match link clicks to opens.

The situation described is most likely the result of some particular aspect of the testing that is preventing Branch from matching the "link click" and "app open" events. This could be a key mismatch, where the link used to open the app has a Test key and the app is using a Live key, or some issue related to the device's advertising identifier being changed between the "link click" and "app open" events.